# Select all the subcolumns with a given name from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that I built using 3 levels of columns, as follows:

```
     a1            a2            a3
     b1     b2     b1     b3     b1     b4
     c1 c2  c1 c2  c1 c2  c1 c2  c1 c2  c1 c2
     ... (data) ...
```

Note that each `a` column may have different `b` subcolumns, but each `b` column has the same `c` subcolumns.

I can extract e.g. the subcolumns from `a2` using `df["a2"]`.

How can I select based on the second or third level without having to specify the first and second level respectively? For instance I would like to say "give me all the `c2` columns you can find" and I would get:

```
     a1     a2     a3
     b1 b2  b1 b3  b1 b4
     ... (data for the c2 columns) ...
```

Or "give me all the `b1` columns" and I would get:

```
     a1     a2     a3
     c1 c2  c1 c2  c1 c2 
     ... (data for the b1 columns) ...
```

Comment: On a side note, it'd be nice if you provide some example data that can be copied and pasted especially since creating MultiIndexes is a bit of a pain. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) provide some info on that. Adapting the examples from there to your example, either use tuples with `slice` objects you pass `None`,

```py
df.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), "c2")]
```

or use `pd.IndexSlice`to use the familiar `:` notation:

```py
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx[:, :, "c2"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a dataframe with a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) the columns are a list of tuples containing the keys of each level.

You can get the columns you want with a list comprehension checking if the name you want is in the tuple:

```py
# get all the "c2"
df[[col for col in df.columns if "c2" in col]]
# get all the "b1"
df[[col for col in df.columns if "b1" in col]]
```

If you want to be sure that the column name is in the right position:

```py
# get all the "c2"
df[[col for col in df.columns if col[2] == "c2"]]
# get all the "b1"
df[[col for col in df.columns if col[1] == "b1"]]
```